# How to authorize/authenticate SHA1 token using Spring Boot (Only on single endpoint)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, interceptor, servlet-filters

Client is sending SHA1 token which is valid upto 24 hours, need to authorize that SHA1 token using Spring Boot.

Ex: 1st service is sending request to 2nd service by passing SHA1 token(valid 24 hour) as part of the header/query param. So 2nd service need to authorize that SHA1 token using Spring Boot.

I have tried with Filter approach. Please help the code snippet, If any new approach also fine.

Please refer below code.

TokenAuthConfig.java file

```
package com.scheduler.config;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;

import com.scheduler.filter.config.TokenAuthFilter;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
@Slf4j
public class TokenAuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Value("${report.rest.key.secret_key}")
   private String SECRET_KEY;

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
       TokenAuthFilter filter = new TokenAuthFilter("Authorization");
       filter.setAuthenticationManager(new AuthenticationManager() {

           @Override
           public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
               log.info("TokenAuthConfig.configure.AuthenticationManager.authenticate SECRET_KEY: " + SECRET_KEY);
               String principal = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
               if (!generateSHA1Token().equals(principal)) {
                   throw new BadCredentialsException("The key was not found or not the expected value.");
               }
               authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
               return authentication;
           }
       });

       httpSecurity.antMatcher("/schedule/v1/status/learner/getAllLearnersReport").csrf().disable().sessionManagement()
               .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().addFilter(filter).authorizeRequests()
               .anyRequest().authenticated();
   }

   private String generateSHA1Token() {
       SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
       simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
       String utcStringDate = simpleDateFormat.format(new java.util.Date());
       String sha1Token = DigestUtils.sha1Hex((SECRET_KEY + utcStringDate));
       log.info("SHA1Token: "+ sha1Token);
       return sha1Token;
   }

}
```

TokenAuthFilter.java file

```
package com.scheduler.filter.config;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class TokenAuthFilter  extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter{


    public String principalRequestHeaderKey;

    public TokenAuthFilter(String principalRequestHeaderKey) {
       log.info("TokenAuthFilter.getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal executed");
       this.principalRequestHeaderKey = principalRequestHeaderKey;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
        log.info("TokenAuthFilter.getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal executed");
        return request.getHeader("token");
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "N/A";
    }

}
```

Comment: Need someone's help. Still, couldn't able to solve.

Comment: Any reason for not using JWT?

Comment: @ngueno I am not sure why they are sending JWT instead of SHA1(I think because of security reason). Management has decided. Please help me on this I am struggling a lot, still couldn't. If any other approach also it's fine.

Comment: I did not understand your issue, you are passing the SHA1 token as far as I see, but you are not validating the expiration time. I strongly reccomend to you change your approach to use a JWT token instead, since it already covers this kind of validation

Comment: I have put the logger the flow is not going into "filter.setAuthenticationManager(new AuthenticationManager() {" . Authentication is not happeing.

Comment: anyone, please?  really I am struggling.

Comment: Here I need to "generate token and compare with client request and authorize the call. We need to generate SHA1 token with the secret key and date (UTC)". Ex: 1. secret key : "cf3c9a11f25e4dba1192ab861216daea" 2. date : "YYYYMMDD (UTC)" 3. token(generated SHA1 token) : secret key + date .

Comment: Not yet resolved!. Need someone's help.